# Construction of triangle

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

I don't know how to prove or disprove the following problem:
How to construct triangle if elements $a$, $b$, $\beta-\gamma$ are given? 
Is it constructible (if not, how to prove it)? Any help is welcome.

Comment: What are $\beta$ and $\gamma$?

Comment: Angles at points B and C of triangle ABC

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain more clearly what you mean by *constructible.*  Do you mean with straightedge and compass?

Comment: Yes, with straightedge and compass.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that such a triangle can be constructed. A triangle construction needs 3 values known. These three values should be valid Congruence rule (such as SAS, SSS, ASA etc.).

Here, we are given 2 edges and difference of angles opposite to those sides. The two edges are 2 values and for third, we have no usable means to deduce. Just one relation between two angles is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

with $a,\angle B,C$ you can construct a triangle.but the extra b may cause conflict unless you ignore it. or you can use $a,b , \angle C$ to construct a triangle.but you have to omit $\angle B$.